# In which Model should I include approved status of a labour getting a particular job?

Tags: python, django, sqlite

So I have created 2 models namely JobModel and LabourModel and I have used Many-to-Many relation between them because 1 labour can apply for multiple jobs and there can be multiple labours applying for 1 job. Now I want to add a feature where the jobcreator can accept/reject a particular labour applying for that particular job and then the labour should be able to see the status regarding approval. I am confused about how should I make a model about this. Here's my current model

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse_lazy, reverse


# Create your models here.
class UserModel(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,related_name = 'user_profile',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    CATEGORY_CHOICES = (('Labour','Labour'),('Owner','Owner'))
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100,choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES,default='NA')
    is_Labour = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_Owner = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
    def get_absolute_url(self):
                return reverse("basic_app:landing")


class JobModel(models.Model):
    user = 
    models.ForeignKey(UserModel,related_name='assigned_job',null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.user.username
    def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse("basic_app:landing")

class LabourModel(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(UserModel,related_name = 
    'assigned_labour',null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    registered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    job_add = models.ManyToManyField(JobModel,related_name = 'labours')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.user.username
    def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse("basic_app:landing")
```

Comment: Is the user in ```JobModel``` the Job Creator ?

Comment: yes the user in jobmodel is the job creator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create multiple many to many fields, one for each state. In this case consider:

1. Neutral.
2. Accepted.
3. Rejected
   One for each required state of the process.
   By default put all labourers in the neutral one. When the employer changes their status to either accepted or rejected remove them from neutral and place them in the respective field. Since many to many fields in django are by default symmetric you can just call it from whatever model to check the status of different jobs.